# Write on two different postgres model?

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

**Question:**

How can I write to two different `Postgres` model and read from one of them?

Actually, I want to migrate some data from one Postgres database to another Postgres database. 
the databases schema are the same. So after migration, I want to write both databases and read from one of them.

**What I tried:**

I tried to handle it by writing a new database router in Django.

```py
from django.conf import settings


class MigrationRouter:

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):

        return settings.READ_ALIAS_DB

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):

        return settings.WRITE_ALIAS_DB

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):

        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):

        if db in (settings.READ_ALIAS_DB, settings.WRITE_ALIAS_DB):
            return True

        return None
```

> If I put both database aliases in the `db_for_write` method that does not work as I expected.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to look into [Postgres High-Availability](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/high-availability.html) database